# How do I pass parameters that contain spaces?

Tags: chocolatey

I want to pass the following "javaoptions" containing a file path with spaces within --params.

`--params "'/javaoptions:-Dwebdriver.jx.browser="C:/Program Files (x86)/TestNav/TestNav.exe"'"`

Comment: One place that we cover this in docs is at https://chocolatey.org/docs/commands-reference#how-to-pass-options-switches.

Comment: Your specific use is pretty involved, shown in your example in the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you can get it to work:

```
choco install -y selenium --params "'/role:node /hub:http://localhost:4444 /capabilitiesJson:$capabilitiesJson /autostart /maxSession:1 /javaoptions:""-Dwebdriver.jx.browser=\`"C:\PROGRA~2\TestNav\TestNav.exe\`"""'" --force -d
```

Note that `$capabilitiesJson` is being interpolated properly.

Comment: Updated answer to handle interpolation

Comment: For parameters with spaces, just pass the values, it will put them to the right item - `--params="'/item1:value /Item2:value with spaces /item3:value3'"` will result in $pp['Item2'] equal to 'value with spaces'. Then you can add quotes later

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to get spaces to work for the example above.  I could get it to build without failing, but the args would end up like this `java -Dwebdriver.jx.browser=C:\Program -jar` instead of this `java -Dwebdriver.jx.browser="C:\PROGRA~2\TestNav\TestNav.exe" -jar`.